# Call SignalR client methods from different process

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, signalr-backplane

I have a website which runs SingalR to inform the front end of certain back end events so it can update. The back end comprises the website back end as well as other services running as console apps, Azure workers, etc. which may or may not be on the same machine as the website runs.

I need some way to grab those back end events and send them down to the clients over SignalR. I would immediately use a service bus, but I'm concerned about managing the subscriptions in the website. I'm interested in eventually using SignalR scale out (with service bus as the backplane), but it seems I won't be able to publish to the backplane topics as the names of the topics is an internal implementation detail.

Question is then: Should I use a service bus subscription in the website and how should I manage the subscription (to ensure that it conforms to the ASP.Net lifecycle), or should I try to use the service bus backplane and how do I publish to it?